# Как в процедуру WinApi окна передать пользовательские данные

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как возможно в callback созданного окна передать свои данные ?
Вроде бы пишут, что при создании окна можно передать указатель на структуру CREATESTRUCT, в которую соответственно можно посетить указатель на мои данные, но что то не работает.

Я делаю так:

```
void My_Create_Window()
{
//Стандартный код создания WinApi окна...

    std::string my_string = "Hello";
    CREATESTRUCT CREATESTRUCT_;
    CREATESTRUCT_.lpCreateParams = &my_string[0];


    my_global_hWnd = CreateWindowW(
        My_WNDCLASSEX.lpszClassName,
        L"Мой Title",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_BORDER,
        -7,
        0,
        800,
        600,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        My_WNDCLASSEX.hInstance,
        &CREATESTRUCT_ 
    );
}
```

Теоретически в соответствии с описанием функции CreateWindowW, последний ее параметр - это значение, которое должно быть передано окну через структуру CREATESTRUCT (член lpCreateParams), на которую указывает параметр lParam сообщения WM_CREATE .

Вроде бы я так и сделал. Теперь я ставлю точку остановки внутри WM_PAINT и проверяю wParam и lParam, но они нулевые - то есть никакого указателя на структуру CREATESTRUCT не передалось.

```
static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND   hWnd, UINT   message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
            //.... тут ставлю точку остановки
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, где я ошибся ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lParam` будет равен `CREATESTRUCT::lpCreateParams`  только при обработке сообщения `WM_CREATE`. Здесь вы можете запомнить его, например, в локальной переменной, а затем использовать ее в `WM_PAINT`.

Будьте осторожны здесь:

```
std::string my_string = "Hello";
CREATESTRUCT CREATESTRUCT_;
CREATESTRUCT_.lpCreateParams = &my_string[0];

my_global_hWnd = CreateWindowW(
    ...
    &CREATESTRUCT_);   // Содержит указатель на локальную переменную my_string!
```

`&my_string_` действителен только в `WM_CREATE`.

Comment: Спасибо! Но, если CREATESTRUCT_ должен быть глобальный, то какой смысл передавать указатель на него в процедуру ? Если я глобальную переменную смог использовать и так из любой части кода, без всяких передач указателя на нее.

Comment: И почему указатель на локальную CREATESTRUCT - должно привести  к падению программы ? Эта CREATESTRUCT - ведь никуда не исчезнет, так как в функции создания окна крутиться бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Суть та же:  если my_string должен быть глобальный, то какой смысл передавать указатель на него в процедуру ? Если я глобальную переменную смог использовать и так из любой части кода, без всяких передач указателя на нее. И теоретически упасть программа не должна, так как my_string - останется существовать до тех пор, пока окно не закроется.

Comment: `my_string` удаляется когда `My_Create_Window` заканчивается. Указатели будуг действительны только при обработке `WM_CREATE`, так как `WM_CREATE` посылается синхронно из `CreateWindow`. Если вы учитываете это, тогда все в порядке.